# Why can't Rails on Passenger find formtastic/bootstrap.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Well, I can't find it in $RUBYLIB/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic

I also have this directory I don't understand:

/home/web/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/formtastic-bootstrap-3428fef4f787

which doesn't include formtastic/bootstrap.rb either, but I don't know
why bundle deposits that gem there.  I run `bundle install` as root, not web
(who owns the Rails files).

There's something very strange about this gem.  When I run `bundle package`
all the other gems in the Gemfile get written to vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
but not this one.  Here's how it's referenced in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap',   :git => "git://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap.git", :branch => "bootstrap-2"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently due to a bad installation of your ruby environment manager. Are you using rbenv or vrm?

I suggest you remove completely rbenv or rvm (google it "remove rvm" or rbenv, it's very easy to find), and you do a new install of your favourite manager (if you hesitate, I would suggest rbenv). Note that you should do the rbenv install and the gems install with a user which is not the web, nor root. You could create a 'deployer' user, and follow those steps https://gist.github.com/olistik/2627011 (this is specific for ubuntu, but it should be easy to adapt)

Comment: On the server I didn't bother using rvm, just installed 1.9.3 in /usr/local and everything was working fine.  Your answer doesn't explain why this only happens with formtastic-bootstrap -- the app pulls in about 15 other gems, and they're all found with no problem.

Comment: The main reason I stopped using rvm is that my apps are served with Passenger on nginx, and I haven't found any info on how to make each virtual server work with a different gemset.  Passenger 4 (currently in beta) allows you to specify a different Ruby for each virtual server.  I don't think rvm works that way, so I'll read up on rbenv

Comment: "Your answer doesn't explain why this only happens with formtastic-bootstrap" -> You know what they say: the error always comes from what's between the screen and the chair. Is that satisfying for an explanation? Hey and also don't bother saying thanks or anything

Comment: Thanks for you last comment Eric, so I guess we can say "the error comes from what was between another chair and another screen" :) Sorry for my comment earlier, and good luck with this. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin.  I'm going to take a bit of time off from this code, and then go with a minimalist gem approach to include only what we need.